# sql columns adding

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add two columns as one column by using this statement

```
SELECT (member_Firstname+''+member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members
```

but it gives all 0 values in mysql workbench

Comment: sql-server is not the right tag if this is for mysql. sql-server is the tag for Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members;
```

This should work always

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) As Name  FROM members WHERE Name Like 'a%'  but i got the error like this      Unknown column 'Name' in 'where clause' would you pls help

Comment: you cannot use alias names for conditions use complete function like ... where concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname)  like 'a%'

Answer (score 2):

I think that in MySQL you should use CONCAT, as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL'); -> 'MySQL'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding is for numbers; for joining strings, use [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(string1,string2,string3,etc) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
```

CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

So for the example

```
SELECT CONCAT(member_Firstname, member_Lastname);
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) As Name FROM members WHERE Name Like 'a%' i got error when i am executing the this statement saying that     " Unknown column 'Name' in 'where clause' "

Comment: You have to write: WHERE concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) LIKE 'a%' INSTEAD OF WHERE NAME LIKE 'a%'